# Python - Dictionary function only one entry for dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am new to python. I have a piece of code that was opening a text reading it, creating a list of words, then from that list create a dictionary of each word with a count of how many times it appears in the list of words. This code was working fine and was printing out the dictionary fine however when i put it in a function and called the function it returns the dictionary but only with one entry. Any ideas why, any help is much appreciated.

```
def createDict():

    wordlist = []


    with open('superman.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as superman:
                for line in superman:
                    for word in line.split():
                        wordlist.append(word)
                   #print(word)    



    table = str.maketrans("!#$%&()*+, ./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~0123456789'“”-''—", 47*' ' )


    lenght = len(wordlist)
    i = 0


    while i < lenght:
            wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].translate(table)
            wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].lower()
            wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].strip()
            i += 1


    wordlist = list(filter(str.strip, wordlist))

    word_dict = {}

    for item in wordlist:
             if item in word_dict.keys():
                word_dict[item] += 1
    else:
                word_dict[item] = 1

    return(word_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try initializing the dictionary outside of the function and then using global inside the function. Is that one item in the dictionary the last iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your indenting in your iterating over the wordlist. Should read:

```py
    for item in wordlist:
        if item in word_dict.keys():
            word_dict[item] += 1
        else:
            word_dict[item] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be an indentation and whitespace issue. Make sure the if and else statements near the end of your function are at the same level.

Below is code I got working with the indentation at the correct level. In addition comments to explain the thought process

```
def createDict():

    wordlist = []


    with open('superman.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as superman:
                for line in superman:
                    for word in line.split():
                        wordlist.append(word)
                   #print(word)    



    table = str.maketrans("!#$%&()*+, ./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~0123456789'“”-''—", 47*' ' )


    lenght = len(wordlist)
    i = 0


    while i < lenght:
            wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].translate(table)
            wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].lower()
            wordlist[i] = wordlist[i].strip()
            i += 1


    wordlist = list(filter(str.strip, wordlist))
    # print(len(wordlist)) # check to see if wordlist is fine. Indeed it is
    word_dict = {}

    for item in wordlist:
        # for dictionaries don't worry about using dict.keys()
        # method. You can use a shorter if [value] in [dict] conditional
        # The issue in your code was the whitespace and indentation
        # of the else statement. 
        # Please make sure that if and else are at the same indentation levels
        # Python reads by indentation and whitespace because it
        # doeesn't use curly brackets like other languages like javascript
        if item in word_dict:
            word_dict[item] += 1
        else:
            word_dict[item] = 1

    return word_dict # print here too
```

Please let me know if you have any questions. Cheers!